# Selenium getting error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This is my selenium test script.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class Adminlogin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //File file = new File("C:/Selenium/IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1/IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/Selenium/IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1/IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        //driver.close(); //Closes the browser
    }

}
```

I am getting this error,

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.53.1.0
Listening on port 35197
Only local connections are allowed
Oct 07, 2016 9:54:51 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake           createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Oct 07, 2016 9:54:52 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake  createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
Oct 07, 2016 9:54:52 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'c7b525d', time: '2016-09-01 14:52:30 -0700'
System info: host: 'user-PC', ip: '192.168.2.113', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:618)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:228)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:172)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:144)
    at Sanitytests.Adminlogin.main(Adminlogin.java:13)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}], required capabilities = null
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'c7b525d', time: '2016-09-01 14:52:30 -0700'
System info: host: 'user-PC', ip: '192.168.2.113', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:597)
```

Comment: getting the same error here.

Comment: i am seeing this too

Comment: you can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40201575/2225030

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had a simmilar error, due to SessionNotCreatedException, caused by DesiredCapabilities discrepancy.

On further research, I went back to https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver.  In the "Required Configuration" section was my solution:

"Additionally, "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and higher. This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet Options dialog."

So, I went to Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced Settings -> Security section.

Unchecked "Enable enhanced protected mode".  Bingo!

I recommend you go through the "Required Configuration" section in the github link above.  There might be other settings you need to apply.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that **IE browser capabilities** had to be changed to support selenium. like zoom, protected mode, etc ... 
try changing IE settings and it should work.