# Unable to create new remote session

Tags: selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

How to resolve this issue. Earlier my code was working, but IE settings were reseted by someone. Now I am getting this exception.

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.53.1.0
Listening on port 16183
Only local connections are allowed
Oct 21, 2016 10:14:12 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Oct 21, 2016 10:14:12 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
Oct 21, 2016 10:14:12 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}], required capabilities = null
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '3169782', time: '2016-09-29 10:24:50 -0700'
System info: host: 'BWT12654001', ip: '10.52.132.157', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:228)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:172)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:144)
    at mypackage.TestIEBrowser.main(TestIEBrowser.java:33)
```

Comment: What `selenium webdriver` version are you using? This week I tested `webdriver` version `3.0.1` and got this same exception for a Remote execution. In  my local machine it's still working. Didn't have the time yet to investigate. The `webdriver` version I have working is `2.53`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can work out of the box without the desired capability settings. Go to internet options>>Security, click on:'Reset all zones to default level and after that, ensure that the 'Enable protected mode' checkbox is ticked for all the four zones.

Comment: This did not help in solving the same problem in Mozilla firefox

Comment: @ChandraShekhar,  this is a solution specifically for IE, not Firefox

Answer (score 4):

First, check your default zoom level in Internet Explorer. If it's not 100% then do the following steps:

- Open Internet Explorer.
- Press Alt + X and then click on Internet Options.
- Click on the Advanced tab.
- Place a check mark on "Reset Zoom level for new Windows and tab"
- Press Apply and ok.
- Close and open Internet Explorer window and check if the Default Zoom
  is set to 100 %.

Once you have done with above steps, add following lines in your code:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
```

Now run your program and it should work.

Hope it will help!!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is discussed on [Selenium project on Github](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6544)

Here is the quote of the most relevant/informative part which helped me to solve the issue:

> The good news is that it looks like the IE driver *mostly* works with IE11, provided
>   that (a) all security zones are set to the same Protected Mode setting and (b) Enhanced
>   Protected Mode is turned off. Note that the standard registry checks that the IE driver
>   uses to test for Protected Mode settings in IE7-10 are broken for IE11, and we've never
>   made any attempt to check for Enhanced Protected Mode, so there's no warning (yet)
>   if you don't have these settings properly set.
>
> The bad news is that cookie manipulation is broken. Badly. If you attempt to set or
>   retrieve cookies, there's a chance that you'll end up with the "Unable to get browser"
>   error encountered before. At the moment, there is no workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (in my case Firefox):

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}}]
```

Using Selenium driver 3.3.1:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And solved it via another version like [3.4+](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/749).

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```